# Informatica BDM string data type

Tags: hive, bigdata, informatica

I am running my mapping on blaze engine and my target **hive** table is transnational.
I have a field coming from source with data type as 32000 (varchar), but when I run the mapping , it is getting failed with following error.

"The Integration Service failed to execute grid mapping with following error [An internal exception occurred with message: The length of the data is larger than the precision of the column.]."

Any insights will be very helpful

Note: 1. My target is a hive table and it's transactional properties are true.
2. I am running this mapping on blaze informatica engine which needs update strategy to be used.
3. Target column field length is also varchar(32000)

Answer (score 1):

- Check that the length of the source data you are ingesting is not bigger that 3200 characters.
- If you using a flat file as source check the delimiters and be sure that is reading correctly the file.